# Autoit script for file upload does not work with selenium script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, autoit

I have below autoIT script to upload file in firefox. It works fine when I run autoit script manually. But it does not work when I use it in my automation selenum script.

## Autoit Script

```
$title = WinGetTitle("File Upload") ; retrives whole window title
WinWait("[CLASS:#32770]")``
WinActive($title)
WinActivate($title)
WinWaitActive($title)
Sleep(700)
send("!n")
Sleep(800)
Send("F:\Projects\MergeServerProject\File\OfflineAgreemntDocuments\DOC\File-1.docx")
Sleep(800)
Send("!o")
```

## Selenium Script

```
clickBrowserBtn(); //This function click on browse button in file upload control on FF
String[]templatenamenew=new String[] {"F:\\Projects\\f1\\scripts\\AutoIt\\FileUpload.exe"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(templatenamenew);
```

## HTML File Upload Control

## Note:

I also try with sendkey function but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this wasn't answered but this should work in C# (not sure about Java, but you didn't specify the language). This line comes after your selenium script has clicked the button/field that opens the window.

```
Process.Start(@"C:\<source>\upload_something.exe", @"C:\<source>\myfile.jpg");
```

Hope it helps!